# how to plot step histograms in ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How can I plot a "step" or "staircase" histogram in ggplot2 in R? something like:

[image]

where width of each horizontal line represents the bin size (of the x-axis values) and the height corresponds to *fraction* of the data that falls in that bin (unlike the attached image where it is a probability density!). is there a way to do this with `geom_histogram`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Use `geom_step`

Generate some data:

```
foo <- data.frame(bar=rnorm(100))
```

Histogram with step geom and counts on y-axis:

```
ggplot(foo,aes(x=bar)) + stat_bin(geom="step")
```

Histogram with step geom and density on y-axis:

```
ggplot(foo,aes(x=bar)) + stat_bin(aes(y=..density..),geom="step")
```

And with "fraction of data that falls into that bin":

```
ggplot(foo,aes(x=bar)) + stat_bin(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)),geom="step")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Might be other, prettier ways to do this but here's one idea.

```
foo <- data.frame(bar = rnorm(100)) + theme_bw()
p <- ggplot(data = foo, aes(x = bar, y = ..count../sum(..count..))) ## or aes(x = bar, y = ..density..) if you want that
p + geom_histogram(size = 2, colour = "red", fill = "white") + geom_histogram(colour = "transparent", fill = "white")
```

[image]

**Edit:**

`geom_histogram(size = 2, colour = "red", fill = "white")` creates this
[image]

I edited the thickness of the outline to `size = 2` to make the final output look nice. It looks awful at this stage. To remove the interior lines you add `geom_histogram(colour = "transparent", fill = "white")` which will draw another histogram on top covering the interior lines (and some of the outline which is why I think `size = 2` looks nice)

Comment: Could you explain why there are two calls to `geom_histogram`?

Comment: @user248237dfsf Just remove the second one and see what happens. It should be obvious.

Comment: @Roland: I see it's a trick to try to get the right color/stepshape... but I don't see how to generalize this to the case where `colour` is set to a variable in the df to encode different conditions.

Comment: @user248237dfsf ziggystar's answer is better and should make it easier to use colours and to draw more than one of these on the same plot. it sounds like that is your final goal

Comment: @JakeBurkhead: agreed though when I try that solution with multiple colours the histograms still occlude each other and it doesn't look good. `geom_density` gets multiple colored lines right, but isn't the right shape so not sure what the answer is

Comment: @user248237dfsf Who is using `geom_density`? My solution uses `geom_step` (which is exactly what you were asking for) and Jake's solution is using `geom_histogram`.

Comment: @ziggystar: I was contrasting geom_density with your solution. When I try your solution with multiple colors, the lines occlude each other

Comment: @user248237dfsf I dont really see what else you would expect. If you are using drawing multiple step histograms with the same bin widths and similar distributions some of the lines will have to be in the same place. May be you want something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957549/overlaying-histograms-with-ggplot2-in-r