# Add transparent histogram outline using relative frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

In `ggplot2`, I'm trying to compare two distributions, one using a filled in histogram, and the other using the outline of a histogram. The goal is to show a relative frequency histogram here, not counts (thus why using `density * width` for the y).

The trouble is that when I use two histograms, the vertical bars still show up, and this is distracting and makes the data hard to read. I could of course use overlapping transparent histograms, but I would prefer an outline approach here. I've tried alternative approaches. (Edit: I later found this nice overview of some of these, though the syntax is a bit out of date: https://kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2021/12/19/comparing-distributions/)

- `geom_histogram` produces internal lines
- `geom_freqpoly` produces jagged lines rather than flat bars (preferrable) or smooth like density
- `stat_bin`/`geom_step` produces a "floating end point" rather than connecting to 0. It also doesn't align with x = 0 or x = 1 at the ends.
- `geom_density` is overly smooth and you are not able to see the shape effectively. It also does not align with x = 0 or x = 1 at the ends. (*I also am not sure how to make the density approximate the %'s found with the other methods, and I likely did this incorrectly*)

If I could get any of these approaches to create the desired result I'd be ecstatic! Another approach is to plot two histograms on top of each other, one with a white fill and one with a transparent fill (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17491302/2934203)

Example reprex:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(22)
# Create Fake Data
flavor <- data.frame(
  color = sample(c('red', 'blue', 'green'), 1500, TRUE),
  flavor = sample.int(n = 100, size = 1500, replace = TRUE) / 100
)

flavor2 <- 
  data.frame(
  color = sample(c('red', 'blue', 'green'), 1500, TRUE),
  flavor = (sample.int(n = 100, size = 1500, replace = TRUE) / 100) ^ 2
)
```

I try plotting all the methods I could find but am not able to produce the result that is like `geom_histogram` but simply without the bars inside.

It can be hard to see the faceted version so this is what it looks like without facets...

[image]

And then with facets...

[image]

Code to produce this below:

```
p1 <- 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = flavor, 
                 mapping = aes(x = flavor,
                               y = after_stat(density * width)),
                 bins = 34,
                 alpha = 0.5) + 
  facet_wrap(~color)
  
ggarrange(plotlist = list(
  'A' = p1 + 
    geom_histogram(data = flavor2,
                   mapping = aes(x = flavor,
                                 y = after_stat(density * width)),
                   fill = NA, 
                   color = 'black',
                   bins = 34) + 
    facet_wrap(~color),
  'B' = p1 + 
    geom_freqpoly(data = flavor2,
                  mapping = aes(x = flavor,
                                y = after_stat(density * width)),
                  bins = 34) + 
    facet_wrap(~color),
  'C' = p1 + 
    stat_bin(data = flavor2, 
             mapping = aes(x = flavor,
                           y = after_stat(density * width)),
             geom = 'step',
             bins = 34,
             color = 'black') + 
    facet_wrap(~color),
  'D' = p1 + 
    geom_density(data = flavor2,
                 mapping = aes(x = flavor,
                               y = after_stat(density / 34)), # Maybe Wrong! 
                 fill = NA, 
                 outline.type = 'full',
                 color = 'black') + 
    facet_wrap(~color)), 
  labels = c('geom_histogram', 'geom_freqpoly', 'stat_bin w/ geom = "step"', 'geom_density'), vjust = 0.75, hjust = -0.5)
```

Comment: Have you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014450/geom-histogram-and-stat-bin-dont-align) for the step graphic?

Comment: I hadn't, that's nice, thanks. Also another tool to make the line return to zero is to use `pad=TRUE`, so that also improves the appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Since `p1` already contains the breaks you want, you can borrow these to construct a histogram object of `flavor2`, which you can then use to calculate and plot a `geom_area`:

```r
p1 <- ggplot(flavor, aes(flavor)) + geom_histogram() 

h <- hist(flavor2$flavor, 
          breaks = unique(round(unlist(ggplot_build(p1)$data[[1]][4:5]), 3)), 
          plot = FALSE)

p1 + geom_area(data = data.frame(flavor = rep(h$breaks, each = 2),
                                 y = c(0, rep(h$counts, each = 2), 0)), 
               aes(y = y), color = "black", fill = "transparent")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is an interesting approach! In my use case, I also have facet grids (in my case it's 4 x 2), it seems unlikely this approach holds since it requires me to construct an additional object for each panel? I modified my example to at least reflect the use of facets.

Comment: @Branfon are you able to specify breaks in advance?

Comment: Yes that would still be consistent across the facets (e.g. within `geom_histogram` I usually supply the `bins` but could use the `breaks` argument instead).