# Density plots with counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need three densities (or smooth histograms) in the same plot.  I am using ggplot, each variable has 1000 observations.  Hence, the number of times a value can occur is a maximum of 1000 times.  Suddenly my code produce extremely high counts for some values.

```
data <- read.table("mydata.txt", sep=",")
df <- data.frame(data)
df.m <- melt(data, variables=)
ggplot(den.m,aes(x=value, fill=variable)) + geom_density(alpha=0.25) 
+ ylab("Counts")
```

How to attach the data to this question?

Comment: you might want to see this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957549/overlaying-histograms-with-ggplot2-in-r

Comment: That code does not produce a plot with counts on the y-axis. It shows the probability density. Use `geom_density(aes(y = ..count..), alpha=0.25)` for that.

Answer (score 1):

@Axeman already gave the right answer in the comments, but nowadays `y=..count..` is deprecated in `ggplot2 3.4.0`, so you should use now `after_stat(count)`. Here is some reproducible code to plot densities with counts on the y-axis:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(aes(y = after_stat(count)), alpha = 0.25)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>