# 2 Binomial Distributions Overlap in R

Tags: r, visualization, binomial-theorem

How would I go about making a graph of two binomial pdfs with different means and have the overlap be filled in with shading or anything for that matter?

Comment: See http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_(ggplot2)/#histogram-and-density-plots-with-multiple-groups

Comment: I don't know what do you mean as "graph of binomial distribution" but maybe here is what you want?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957549/overlaying-histograms-with-ggplot2-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- rbind(data.frame(binom=rbinom(1000, 20, 0.2), binomial.p='0.2') , data.frame(binom=rbinom(1000, 20, 0.5),binomial.p='0.5'))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(binom, fill=binomial.p)) + 
geom_histogram(position = 'dodge', binwidth = 1) + 
xlab('Number of success (n=20)')
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(binom, fill=binomial.p)) + 
geom_density(alpha=0.2) + 
xlab('Number of success (n=20)')
```

[image]