# how to merge two seperate histograms into one

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
library("ggplot2") 

x1 = as.numeric(x=QualidadeARO3$Ilhavo)
x2 = as.numeric(x=QualidadeARO3$VNTelha_Maia)

ggplot (QualidadeARO3, aes(x=x1, color="Ílhavo")) +
  geom_histogram(fill="black", position="dodge", alpha = 0.2) +
  theme(legend.position="top") + 
  xlab("microgramas por metro cúbico") + 
  ylab("horas") 

ggplot(QualidadeARO3, aes(x=x2, color="VN Telha-Maia")) +
  geom_histogram(fill="blue", position="dodge", alpha = 0.2)+
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  xlab("microgramas por metro cúbico") + 
  ylab("horas")
```

Where `QualidadeARO3` is a data sheet imported from Excel that looks like this:

[image]

And

```
ggplot (QualidadeARO3, aes(x=x1, color="Ílhavo")) +
  geom_histogram(fill="black", position="dodge", alpha = 0.2) +
  theme(legend.position="top") + 
  xlab("microgramas por metro cúbico") + 
  ylab("horas")
```

gives the following ouput:
[image]

and

```
ggplot(QualidadeARO3, aes(x=x2, color="VN Telha-Maia")) +
  geom_histogram(fill="blue", position="dodge", alpha = 0.2)+
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  xlab("microgramas por metro cúbico") + 
  ylab("horas")
```

gives:
[image]

This is good and all so far, but my problem is that both graphs "run" independently, i.e., when I call the second `ggplot` the first graph disappears, when I want to overlap both into a single histogram, as well as both color labels.
I have seen [Overlaying histograms with ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957549/overlaying-histograms-with-ggplot2-in-r) , but still no clue. Any help?

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: @Quinten I can give you a link to it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HfGKUktbU3dHLEOWhzUR_PS_kFUpy0RL/edit#gid=169599789

Comment: Copy the output of `dput(df)` and paste that in your question above please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having separate geom layers like this:

```
ggplot (QualidadeARO3) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=x1, color="Ílhavo", fill="Ílhavo"),
                 position="dodge", alpha = 0.2)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=x2, color="VN Telha-Maia", fill="VN Telha-Maia"),
                 position="dodge", alpha = 0.2)+
  scale_fill_manual("Type", labels = c("Ílhavo", "VN Telha-Maia"),
                      values= c("black", "blue")) +
  scale_color_discrete("Type", labels = c("Ílhavo", "VN Telha-Maia")) +
  theme(legend.position="top") + 
  xlab("microgramas por metro cúbico") + 
  ylab("horas")
```

You can also use `scale_fill_manual` instead of `scale_color_discrete` if you want to have specific colors.