# How to make R and p italic in geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

**Update** with the facet part the plot should look like this unless R and p (the letters) should be italic:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color = factor(am)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(x = 25, y = 500,
                label = ifelse(am == 0, "R = 0.5998324, p = 0.0002", "")),
            color = "black")+
  facet_wrap(. ~ am)
```

[image]

**Original question**
I have this example plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color = factor(am)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(x = 25, y = 300,
                label = ifelse(am == 0, expression(paste("R = 0.5998324, ", italic("p = 0.0002"))), "")),
            color = "black")
```

[image]
I would like to make `R` and `p` in `geom_text()` `italic`:

I tried with `expression`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color = factor(am)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(x = 25, y = 300,
                label = ifelse(am == 0, expression(paste("R = 0.5998324, ", italic("p = 0.0002"))), "")),
            color = "black")
```

I get this error:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale
for object of type <expression>. Defaulting
to continuous.
Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics are not valid data
  columns.
✖ The following aesthetics are invalid:
✖ `label = ifelse(...)`
ℹ Did you mistype the name of a data column
  or forget to add `after_stat()`?
```

How could I fix? The ifelse is important because in real life I facet the data and using unicode makes it possible but changes the font!

Comment: Why the `ifelse`? With `geom_text(aes(x = 25, y = 300),
                label = expression(paste(italic("R"), "= 0.5998324, ", italic("p"), "= 0.0002")),
            color = "black")` this works well I think

Comment: @Maël The same task should be applied to this code <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76098463/assistence-in-creating-point-biserial-correlation-plot>. I used a more simply code to make it minimal.

Comment: Use facet in your example code, and explain how/where do you expect the text to appear. Within geom_text there is only one point 25, 300. But ifelse would return nrow(mtcars) values, not sure how ggplot supposed to handle this case.

Comment: tarjae, you will probably know, but I generally advise to use annotate(geom = "text") if you have a single label, or make a separate data frame. geom_text will make your text appear ragged as it will draw many labels. Not that this really matters for this example, but I feel that as a valued user with high reputation it would be great if you could lead our less experienced users with good (better:) code examples...

Comment: @tjebo Thank you very much for your input. And I fully agree to make better code examples (which I try). But this time I was in hurry and needed just a quick solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option using `parse=TRUE` in `geom_text` with `italic` while keeping the `ifelse` like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color = factor(am)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(x = 25, y = 500,
                label = ifelse(am == 0, 'paste(italic("R")," = 0.5998324, ",italic("p")," = 0.0002")', "")),
            color = "black",
            parse = TRUE)+
  facet_wrap(. ~ am)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Your solution seems to work well with my original data. And now I also understand why I got the problem. In facet_wrap I do not use the original `am` column instead I created an `label_am` and therefore the `subset` version of @benson23 is showing the geom_text on both facets!. The only thing with your solution is that the font is getting very blurry. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: You could add `check_overlap = TRUE` to remove the blurry font. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952832/ggplot2-is-there-a-fix-for-jagged-poor-quality-text-produced-by-geom-text) clarifies the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe only include a subset of data (`am == 0`) to `geom_text`? Facet still works after this.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, color = factor(am)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(data = subset(mtcars, am == 0), aes(x = 25, y = 300),
            label = expression(paste(italic("R"), " = 0.5998324, ", italic("p"), " = 0.0002")),
            color = "black", check_overlap = T) +
  facet_grid(~am)
#> Warning in is.na(x): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type
#> 'expression'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1 for the idea. The thing is only `R` and only `p` should be italic, not the numbers!

Comment: @TarJae Updated to only include corresponding strings in `italic()` :)